# MVC 3: Aggregate model problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my HomeController I have the following 3 queries, notice that the 3rd one is not a "ToList", but just the first result being used.

```
var model = new AggregateModel();
model.Tasks = db.Task.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Completed == false) && (n.Due > dateTime)).ToList();
model.Events = db.Events.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Start < dateTime)).OrderBy(p => p.Start).ToList();
model.NextEvent = db.Events.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Start < dateTime)).OrderBy(p => p.Start).First();
```

And in the Model file I have the following model:

```
public class AggregateModel
{
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public List<Event> NextEvent { get; set; }
}
```

I need to change the "NextEvent" definition in the model file from "public List" to a different type, but I am not sure of the correct term needed.

Many thanks for any help.

[EDIT]

Basically from the NextEvent model, I want to pull the one result and display it in my view, but the following has a red line under the foreach.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.NextEvent)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.EventId })</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: umm .. it should be `public Event NextEvent` ..shouldn't it ?

Comment: Wow you keep posting each step of your development process here don't you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for

```
public Event NextEvent {get;set;}
```

Edit:
Ad. second 'foreach' question. Foreach is used only to iterate collections, but NextEvent is a single entity. So there is nothing to iterate with foreach. You can access your NextEvent like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(Model.NextEvent.Title, "Details", new { id = Model.NextEvent.EventId })</li>
```

At least that should work if you didn't rename default model in view.

`Model` = AggregateModel
`Model.NextEvent` = AggregateModel.NextEvent

Comment: This is great, apart from in my view, under the "@foreach", I get a red line, saying this type of statement cannot be performed on this operator. Any reason why?

Comment: @dalehumphries: You would have to provide your code. What are you sending into that foreach? How? Where... I don't see how it is related to your initial question.

Comment: @dalehumphries: I have added solution into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

remove the foreach, change the code to >

`<li>@Html.ActionLink(Model.NextEvent.Title, "Details", new { id = Model.NextEvent.EventId</li>`